# TypeORM conditional querying many to many relations

Tags: mysql, typescript, many-to-many, typeorm

Let's say I've a `colors` table and an `items` table, with a `@ManyToMany` relation between these 2 tables (an item can have many colors and a color can have many items).

Using TypeORM, I would like to get all items that match only one or more provided colors. 
If an item has an additional color that is not specified in the query, it should not be retrieved.

```js
const matchingColors = ['green', 'blue'];
const query = await this.itemRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('item')
  .innerJoin('item.colors', 'color', 'color.name IN (:...matchingColors)', { matchingColors })
  .getMany();
```

In my example above I would like to get **all** items that match the `matchingColors` array, so all items that have green, or blue, or green and blue color(s). So if an item has the blue and red colors, or only red (or no color), it should be excluded from the results.

Currently, I didn't find a proper way to do it. The query in my example above doesn't work correctly. My dream is to make it work using only 1 SQL query. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const matchingColors = ['green', 'blue'];
const items = await this.itemRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('item')
  .innerJoinAndSelect(
      'item.colors',
      'color',
      '"color"."name" IN (:...matchingColors)',
      { matchingColors }
   )
  .getMany();
```